# application running from windows service in python stop when logoff windows XP

Tags: python, windows, service, logoff

I created a windows service in python (windows XP), in this service i run a python server program (with `p = subprocess.Popen(Arg)`), when i logoff the service is running but my application is stopped.
What is a probem right, other ?
Can someone help me?

Thanks

Source Code :

```
class PythonService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    # you can NET START/STOP the service by the following name
    _svc_name_ = "PythonService"
    # this text shows up as the service name in the Service
    # Control Manager (SCM)
    _svc_display_name_ = "server service"
    # this text shows up as the description in the SCM
    _svc_description_ = "This service run a server"


    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        # create an event to listen for stop requests on
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("PythonService Service is starting")


    # core logic of the service   
    def SvcDoRun(self):   
        rc = None      
        PathPython = "c:/python2.6/python.exe"
        Script = "c:/PythonService/service.py"
        sJson = "c:/PythonService/service_static.json"


        Arg = [PathPython,Script,"-c",sJson] 
        process_arreter = 1

        try :
            # run a server
            p = subprocess.Popen(Arg)
        except OSError, why:
            msgerror = "PythonService Service is not running :" + os.strerror(why.errno) + " ["+PathPython+","+Script+","+sJson+"]"
            servicemanager.LogErrorMsg(msgerror)       
            return

        # if the stop event hasn't been fired keep looping
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("PythonService Service is running")
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            # block for 5 seconds and listen for a stop event
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 5000)
            if (p.poll()!=None):
                if process_arreter: 
                    servicemanager.LogWarningMsg("Server-Engine is stopped (failed)")
                process_arreter = 0

        if process_arreter:
            try:
                p.terminate()
                servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Server-Engine is now stopped")
            except :
                pass


    # called when we're being shut down
    def SvcStop(self):
        # tell the SCM we're shutting down
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        # fire the stop event
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("PythonService Service is stopped")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(PythonService)`
```

Answer (score 0):

What user is your service running as, and does it have permissions to all of it's required functions?

Services do NOT run in the same context as a user unless you specify them having those privileges.

You have to specify your file path if you are within a windows service, and make sure that they paths have permission to be read an written 
 but it wasn't done and I pulled my hair out for no reason.

Comment: George, my service is running with administrator permissions, and the python projet is installed with administrator permission; I think that a have to trap the logoff event, to avoid the stop of the server.

Comment: I know that this will be a strange question, but exactly "How are you starting and stopping the service"?

Answer (score 0):

```
# first try to get the currently logged on user
# works okay for a straight python app / prog
if sys.platform == 'win32':
     userName = os.getenv('USERNAME')
else: #linux but also not forgetting mac
      userName = os.getenv('USER')

# when code run in a python win service userName in None here!!!!
# so lets get platform specific
if not userName:
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        import win32api
        userName = win32api.GetUserName()

# do you see 'SYSTEM' here - NOT the currently logged on user
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow your service to keep running even when your user logs off you need to specified a control handler that would always return `True` before starting it.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(lambda x: True, True)
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(PythonService)
```